# Wordpress redirect to non-existing language-directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

following situation. I have a blog which is installed in /blog/ - the site is available in 3 languages (de, at, ch), each one should link to /language/blog/, but they should all show the content of /blog/ (why you ask? SEO purposes...)

This is the .htaccess I've got:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(de|at|ch)/blog/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/%2?hl=%1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The language-directories do not really exist, only the impression should be made.

The "hl" (hreflang) query param is for later use in the script - the param is being sent as expected. So now it is basically working (tested on a non-wordpress directory) - but when I'm using it in the Wordpress environment, all I get is the content of the 404.php-Template.

Used version: 3.4.2

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code you added in a separate htaccess that is in the root, and not in the `/blog` directory.

Comment: sorry that I forgot to mention it, but it already is in the root directory.